# Index selection in CockroachDB

Tags: cockroachdb

How do I know which index CockroachDB will select for my query? How do I make sure I’m not performing a full table scan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty lengthy topic; there's [an entire blog post devoted to the subject](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/blog/index-selection-cockroachdb-2/), which might be the best source for understanding how it works in CockroachDB.

To see which indexes CockroachDB is using for a given query, you can use the [`EXPLAIN`](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/explain.html) statement, which will print out the query plan, including any indexes that are being used:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT col1 FROM tbl1;
```

If you'd like to tell the query planner which index to use, you can do so [via some special syntax for index hints](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/select.html#force-index-selection-index-hints):

```
SELECT col1 FROM tbl1@idx1;
```